# How to capture raw text in dialogue flow in google actions?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to make a simple app like Quora using Actions on Google where anyone can ask a question. I am trying to capture raw text in Dialogflow, but I'm not able to do that. I am trying using `actions_intent_TEXT` but the raw text isn't going there. How can I do this?

Comment: You're mixing several concepts here, so it is unclear what you've done and why it isn't working. If you can update your question to include screen shots and code, we can probably help you a little better. See [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Answer (score 0):

Your *action*, which is activated by a user's *intent* needs to accept one or more *parameters* that the user provides.  That parameter can then be passed to the *fulfillment* for the action (which might be a Firebase function, or something else.)

As the first commenter said, you seem to need a brief intro into some of this lingo.  [I'd recommend you look at the terminology provided by Google.](https://developers.google.com/actions/glossary)

If you want a step-by-step tutorial, [this is a good one to start with](https://medium.com/swlh/chapter-6-how-to-build-a-google-home-app-with-dialogflow-overview-4549d92d8d6a?source=user_profile---------14------------------).